# Deleting registry key based on one of it's values?

Tags: c#, registry

I'm working on a simple application to delete user profile entries from the registry, but I've ran into an issue.

So first, I'm getting all the subkeys that are in the ProfileList through the following code:

```
List<string> KeyList = new List<string>();

        RegistryKey ProfileList = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList\\");
        foreach (string ProfileKey in ProfileList.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            KeyList.Add(ProfileKey);
        }
```

From there, I'm getting the ProfileImagePath value of each of those keys and adding them to a checked list box:

```
KeyList.ForEach(delegate(string ProfileKey)
        {
            ProfileList = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\ProfileList\\" + ProfileKey + "\\");
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(ProfileList.GetValue("ProfileImagePath").ToString());
        });
```

Then, when the user clicks the delete button, I want the application to delete the user profiles that are checked. However, I would have to get the value of each checked item (which looks something like C:/Users/Name) and determine which registry keys to delete. I assume I can do this in a foreach loop, but I'm not quite sure how.
What is the best way to go around doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You could execute this code when the user clicks a button such as "Delete Selected Users". Here is the shell of the code:

```
string[] CheckItemsArray = new string[checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count+1];
        checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.CopyTo(CheckItemsArray, 0);

        foreach (string CheckedItem in CheckItemsArray)
        {
            if (CheckedItem != null)
            {
                //your deleting logic here

            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, it almost works. I finished my delete logic but I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException when the items in the checked list box are copied to the array. Any ideas?

EDIT: Never mind. Messed something up. Thanks again!